# Mock dependency in Jest with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, typescript, jestjs

When testing a module that has a dependency in a different file and assigning that module to be a `jest.mock`, TypeScript gives an error that the method `mockReturnThisOnce` (or any other `jest.mock` method) does not exist on the dependency, this is because it is previously typed.

What is the proper way to get TypeScript to inherit the types from `jest.mock`?

Here is a quick example.

Dependency

```
const myDep = (name: string) => name;
export default myDep;
```

test.ts

```
import * as dep from '../dependency';
jest.mock('../dependency');

it('should do what I need', () => {
  //this throws ts error
  // Property mockReturnValueOnce does not exist on type (name: string)....
  dep.default.mockReturnValueOnce('return')
}
```

I feel like this is a very common use case and not sure how to properly type this.

Comment: If i remember right you have to mock before you import. Just switch the first 2 lines. But i'm not sure about this.

Comment: @ThomasKleßen Modules imported via ES6 `import` are evaluated first, no matter if you put some code before the import. So this won't work.

Comment: @Thomas Calls to jest.mock are hoisted to the top of the code - jest magic I guess... ([ref](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#replacing-the-mock-using-mockimplementationdocsenmock-function-apimockfnmockimplementationfn-or-mockimplementationoncedocsenmock-function-apimockfnmockimplementationoncefn)) However, this creates some pitfalls, e.g. when [calling jest.mock() with the module factory parameter](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmockdocsenjest-objectjestmockmodulename-factory-options-with-the-module-factory-parameter) therefore name mock functions as `mock...`

Answer (score 186):

You can use type casting and your `test.ts` should look like this:

```
import * as dep from '../dependency';
jest.mock('../dependency');

const mockedDependency = <jest.Mock<typeof dep.default>>dep.default;

it('should do what I need', () => {
  //this throws ts error
  // Property mockReturnValueOnce does not exist on type (name: string)....
  mockedDependency.mockReturnValueOnce('return');
});
```

TS transpiler is not aware that `jest.mock('../dependency');` changes type of `dep` thus you have to use type casting. As imported `dep` is not a type definition you have to get its type with `typeof dep.default`.

### Here are some other useful patterns I've found during my work with Jest and TS

When imported element is a class then you don't have to use typeof for example:

```
import { SomeClass } from './SomeClass';

jest.mock('./SomeClass');

const mockedClass = <jest.Mock<SomeClass>>SomeClass;
```

This solution is also useful when you have to mock some node native modules:

```
import { existsSync } from 'fs';

jest.mock('fs');

const mockedExistsSync = <jest.Mock<typeof existsSync>>existsSync;
```

In case you don't want to use jest automatic mock and prefer create manual one

```
import TestedClass from './TestedClass';
import TestedClassDependency from './TestedClassDependency';

const testedClassDependencyMock = jest.fn<TestedClassDependency>(() => ({
  // implementation
}));

it('Should throw an error when calling playSomethingCool', () => {
  const testedClass = new TestedClass(testedClassDependencyMock());
});
```

`testedClassDependencyMock()` creates mocked object instance
`TestedClassDependency` can be either class or type or interface

Comment: I had to use `jest.fn(() =>...` instead of `jest.fn<TestedClassDependency>(() =>...` (I just removed the type casting after jest.fn) because IntelliJ is complaining. Otherwise this answer helped me thanks! Using this in my package.json: "@types/jest": "^24.0.3"

Comment: what does `jest.mock('./SomeClass');` in above code?

Comment: Hum it doesn't work anymore with last TS version and jest 24 :(

Comment: @Reza it's auto mock, https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#automatic-mock

Comment: The `<jest.Mock<SomeClass>>SomeClass` expression is producing a TS error for me: `Conversion of type 'typeof SomeClass' to type 'Mock<SomeClass, any>' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Type 'typeof SomeClass' is missing the following properties from type 'Mock<SomeClass, any>': getMockName, mock, mockClear, mockReset, and 11 more.ts(2352)`

Comment: @the21st In this case you should use something like `(SomeClass as unknown) as <jest.Mock<SomeClass>>`.  Please note that this code is using another form of type casting, which is more preferred now.

Comment: I see, thanks. Though at that point I think it's easier (and less ugly) to just use `// @ts-ignore` and on the next line e.g. `const mockedInstance = new SomeClass()`

Comment: See the answer by me for the proper solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60244371/1133802

Comment: Try `const SoundPlayerMock = SoundPlayer as jest.MockedClass<typeof SoundPlayer>;`

Answer (score 178):

**Use the [`mocked` helper per the documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api/#jestmockedsource-options)**

```js
// foo.spec.ts
import { foo } from './foo'
jest.mock('./foo')

// here the whole foo var is mocked deeply
const mockedFoo = jest.mocked(foo, true)

test('deep', () => {
  // there will be no TS error here, and you'll have completion in modern IDEs
  mockedFoo.a.b.c.hello('me')
  // same here
  expect(mockedFoo.a.b.c.hello.mock.calls).toHaveLength(1)
})

test('direct', () => {
  foo.name()
  // here only foo.name is mocked (or its methods if it's an object)
  expect(jest.mocked(foo.name).mock.calls).toHaveLength(1)
})
```

Comment: Here are a few more examples of using `ts-jest` and classes: https://github.com/tbinna/ts-jest-mock-examples and this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58639737/import-function-from-a-jest-manual-mock-with-typescript/61358020#61358020

Comment: @Tobi The test in the repo fails

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up @Kreator. Do you see the [same issue as the one reported](https://github.com/tbinna/ts-jest-mock-examples/issues/2)? I could not reproduce any issue yet.

Comment: @Kreator just merged a PR. Let me know if the issue persists

Comment: Is there an equivalent package, for us that have to run eslint?

Comment: Note that ts-jest/utils is now being deprecated in favour of the "official" jest-mocks package.

Comment: TypeError: jest.mocked is not a function

Answer (score 41):

There are two solutions tested for **TypeScript version 3.x and 4.x**, both are casting desired function

**1) Use jest.MockedFunction**

```
import * as dep from './dependency';

jest.mock('./dependency');

const mockMyFunction = dep.myFunction as jest.MockedFunction<typeof dep.myFunction>;
```

**2) Use jest.Mock**

```
import * as dep from './dependency';

jest.mock('./dependency');

const mockMyFunction = dep.default as jest.Mock;
```

---

There is no difference between these two solutions. The second one is shorter and I would therefore suggest using that one.

Both casting solutions allows to call any jest mock function on `mockMyFunction` like `mockReturnValue` or `mockResolvedValue`
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api.html

```
mockMyFunction.mockReturnValue('value');
```

`mockMyFunction` can be used normally for expect

```
expect(mockMyFunction).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

Comment: Thank you! I like this more than the accepted answer because a) it's easier to read IMO and b) it works in JSX without causing syntax errors

Comment: I get "typeError: mockMyFunction.mockReturnValue is not a function"

Comment: @Spock I've solved using require instead of import

Comment: 2 almost worked for me but my module does not have a default export so I got the following:

```TS2339: Property  default  does not exist on type```

But I was able to use 1 to just export the functions I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

I use the pattern from @types/jest/index.d.ts just above the type def for Mocked (line 515):

```
import { Api } from "../api";
jest.mock("../api");

const myApi: jest.Mocked<Api> = new Api() as any;
myApi.myApiMethod.mockImplementation(() => "test");
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could just do `const myApi = new Api() as jest.Mocked<Api>;`

Comment: @neoflash: Not in strict mode in TypeScript 3.4 - it will complain that Api type does not sufficiently overlap with `jest.Mock<Api>`. You'd have to go with `const myApi = new Api() as any as jest.Mock<Api>` and I'd say the one above looks a bit better than double assertion.

Comment: @tuptus: is strict mode fresh for 3.4? Do you have a link please regarding this?

Comment: @elmpp: not sure what you mean. By "strict mode" I meant having `"strict": true` in tsconfig.json. This covers stuff like `noImplicitAny`, `strictNullChecks` etc., so you don't have to set it to true for them individually.

Comment: I don't get it. Why are you only stubbing the method of one instance, i.e. `myApi`? It won't generically stub all other instances initiated by class `Api` within the module being tested, right?

Comment: What if API constructor parameters? Typescript is complaining I have to pass them even though I don't need to really.

Comment: I used `const myApi: jest.Mocked<Api> = new Api() as jest.Mocked<Api>;` to avoid eslint complaint about `any`

Answer (score 15):

#### Cast `as jest.Mock`

Simply casting the function to `jest.Mock` should do the trick:

```
(dep.default as jest.Mock).mockReturnValueOnce('return')
```

Answer (score 11):

The latest jest allows you to do this very easily with [jest.mocked](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestmockedtitem-t-deep--false)

```
import * as dep from '../dependency';

jest.mock('../dependency');

const mockedDependency = jest.mocked(dep);

it('should do what I need', () => {
  mockedDependency.mockReturnValueOnce('return');
});
```

Answer (score 8):

#### Use `as jest.Mock` and nothing else

The most concise way of mocking a module exported as `default` in ts-jest that I can think of really boils down to casting the module as `jest.Mock`.

Code:

```
import myDep from '../dependency' // No `* as` here

jest.mock('../dependency')

it('does what I need', () => {
  // Only diff with pure JavaScript is the presence of `as jest.Mock`
  (myDep as jest.Mock).mockReturnValueOnce('return')

  // Call function that calls the mocked module here

  // Notice there's no reference to `.default` below
  expect(myDep).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

Benefits:

- does not require referring to the `default` property anywhere in the test code - you reference the actual exported function name instead,
- you can use the same technique for mocking named exports,
- no `* as` in the import statement,
- no complex casting using the `typeof` keyword,
- no extra dependencies like `mocked`.

Answer (score 8):

As of Jest `24.9.0` here is how you can mock and correctly type both your Class/Object/function and Jest properties.

[jest.MockedFunction](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#jestmockedfunction)

[jest.MockedClass](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#jestmockedclass)

What we would like for a typed mock is that the mocked object type contains the union of the mocked object type and the type of Jest mocks.

```
import foo from 'foo';
jest.mock('foo');

const mockedFoo = foo as jest.MockedFunction<typeof foo>;
// or: const mockedFooClass = foo as jest.MockedClass<typeof FooClass>;


mockedFoo.mockResolvedValue('mockResult');

// Or:
(mockedFoo.getSomething as jest.MockedFunction<typeof mockedFoo.getSomething>).mockResolvedValue('mockResult');
```

As you can see, you can either manually cast what you need or you'll need something to traverse all *foo*'s properties/methods to type/cast everything.

To do that (deep mock types) you can use [jest.mocked()](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#jestmockedclass) introduced in Jest `27.4.0`

```
import foo from 'foo';
jest.mock('foo');

const mockedFoo = jest.mocked(foo, true); 

mockedFoo.mockImplementation() // correctly typed
mockedFoo.getSomething.mockImplementation() // also correctly typed
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's what I did with **jest@24.8.0** and **ts-jest@24.0.2**:

source:

```
class OAuth {

  static isLogIn() {
    // return true/false;
  }

  static getOAuthService() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

test:

```
import { OAuth } from '../src/to/the/OAuth'

jest.mock('../src/utils/OAuth', () => ({
  OAuth: class {
    public static getOAuthService() {
      return {
        getAuthorizationUrl() {
          return '';
        }
      };
    }
  }
}));

describe('createMeeting', () => {
  test('should call conferenceLoginBuild when not login', () => {
    OAuth.isLogIn = jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() => {
      return false;
    });

    // Other tests
  });
});
```

This is how to mock a non-default class and it's static methods:

```
jest.mock('../src/to/the/OAuth', () => ({
  OAuth: class {
    public static getOAuthService() {
      return {
        getAuthorizationUrl() {
          return '';
        }
      };
    }
  }
}));
```

Here should be some type conversion from the type of your class to `jest.MockedClass` or something like that. But it always ends up with errors. So I just used it directly, and it worked.

```
test('Some test', () => {
  OAuth.isLogIn = jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() => {
    return false;
  });
});
```

But, if it's a function, you can mock it and do the type conversation.

```
jest.mock('../src/to/the/Conference', () => ({
  conferenceSuccessDataBuild: jest.fn(),
  conferenceLoginBuild: jest.fn()
}));
const mockedConferenceLoginBuild = conferenceLoginBuild as 
jest.MockedFunction<
  typeof conferenceLoginBuild
>;
const mockedConferenceSuccessDataBuild = conferenceSuccessDataBuild as 
jest.MockedFunction<
  typeof conferenceSuccessDataBuild
>;
```

Answer (score 5):

I have found this in `@types/jest`:

```
/**
  * Wrap a function with mock definitions
  *
  * @example
  *
  *  import { myFunction } from "./library";
  *  jest.mock("./library");
  *
  *  const mockMyFunction = myFunction as jest.MockedFunction<typeof myFunction>;
  *  expect(mockMyFunction.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe(42);
*/
```

**Note:** When you do `const mockMyFunction = myFunction` and then something like `mockFunction.mockReturnValue('foo')`, you're a changing `myFunction` as well.

Source: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/jest/index.d.ts#L1089

Answer (score 2):

The top rated solution by Artur Górski does not work with the last TS and Jest.
Use [MockedClass](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#jestmockedclass)

```
import SoundPlayer from '../sound-player';

jest.mock('../sound-player'); // SoundPlayer is now a mock constructor

const SoundPlayerMock = SoundPlayer as jest.MockedClass<typeof SoundPlayer>;
```

Comment: Note: if the thing you're mocking is a function, use `MockedFunction` instead.

Answer (score -1):

A recent library solves this problem with a babel plugin: https://github.com/userlike/joke

Example:

```js
import { mock, mockSome } from 'userlike/joke';

const dep = mock(import('./dependency'));

// You can partially mock a module too, completely typesafe!
// thisIsAMock has mock related methods
// thisIsReal does not have mock related methods
const { thisIsAMock, thisIsReal } = mockSome(import('./dependency2'), () => ({ 
  thisIsAMock: jest.fn() 
}));

it('should do what I need', () => {
  dep.mockReturnValueOnce('return');
}
```

Be aware that `dep` and `mockReturnValueOnce` are fully type safe. On top, tsserver is aware that `depencency` was imported and was assigned to `dep` so all automatic refactorings that tsserver supports will work too.

Note: I maintain the library.

Answer (score -1):

This is ugly, and in fact getting away from this ugliness is why I even looked at this question, but to get strong typing from a module mock, you can do something like this:

```ts
const myDep = (require('./dependency') as import('./__mocks__/dependency')).default;

jest.mock('./dependency');
```

Make sure you require `'./dependency'` rather than the mock directly, or you will get two different instantiations.

Answer (score -1):

For me this was enough:

```js
let itemQ: queueItemType
jest.mock('../dependency/queue', () => {
    return {
        add: async (item: queueItemType, ..._args: any) => {
            // then we can use the item that would be pushed to the queue in our tests
            itemQ = item
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                resolve('Mocked')
            })
        },
    }
})
```

Then, whenever the add method is called it will execute this code above instead of pushing it to the queue, in this case.

Answer (score -1):

With TypeScript 2.8 we can do like this with `ReturnType`:

```
import * as dep from "./dependency"

jest.mock("./dependency")

const mockedDependency = <jest.Mock<ReturnType<typeof dep.default>>>dep.default

it("should do what I need", () => {
  mockedDependency.mockReturnValueOnce("return")
})
```