# Nest.js Jest cannot mock testing app but can mock testing controller

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, nestjs, supertest

I have a Jest Nest.js controller test where I can stub the calls to the live database. It works fine.

I would like to have 'stubbed e2e' tests using nests HTTP Server (I am using supertest). However, when I import the `AppModule` I cannot seem to get jest to override anything.

Here is my working controller setup using stubbed classes.

```
describe('Working stubbed controller test', () => {
    let controller;

    beforeAll(async () => {
        const moduleFixture = await Test.createTestingModule({
            controllers: [MyController],
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: ObjectInjectionDependency,
                    useClass: ObjectInjectionDependency
                },
                {
                    provide: '@string/injection/dependency',
                    useClass: DbOjectMockIAmUsing
                },
                {
                    provide: '@another/string/injection/dependency',
                    useValue: '@another/string/injection/dependency',
                },
                {
                    provide: DbConnection,
                    useValue: {
                        selectOne: () => null,
                        selectAll: () => null
                    }
                }
            ]
        })
        .compile();

        controller = moduleFixture.get<MyController>(MyController)
    });

    it('/GET url', async () => {
        const request = {
            method: "GET",
            params: {},
            query: {}
        }

        expect(
            await controller.all(request)
        ).toHaveProperty(
            'data'
        )
    });
});
```

Here is my unsuccessful attempt at incorporating stubbed classes along with the HTTP server using `supertest`. The stubbed classes are ignored.

```
describe('Bypassing stubs application test', () => {
    let app;
    let server;

    beforeAll(async () => {
        const moduleFixture = await Test.createTestingModule({
            imports: [AppModule],
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: ObjectInjectionDependency,
                    useClass: ObjectInjectionDependency
                },
                {
                    provide: '@string/injection/dependency',
                    useClass: DbOjectMockIAmUsing
                },
                {
                    provide: '@another/string/injection/dependency',
                    useValue: '@another/string/injection/dependency',
                },
                {
                    provide: DbConnection,
                    useValue: {
                        selectOne: () => null,
                        selectAll: () => null
                    }
                }
            ]
        })
        .compile();

        app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
        server = app.getHttpServer()
        await app.init();
    });

    it('/GET roots', async () => {
        expect(
            await request(server).get('/myEndpoint')
        ).toMatchObject({
            'statusCode': 200
        })
    });
});
```

I tried using the `overrideProvider()` methods but they didn't work either

```
const moduleFixture = await Test.createTestingModule({
    imports: [AppModule]
})
.overrideProvider(ObjectInjectionDependency)
    .useClass(ObjectInjectionDependency)
.overrideProvider('@string/injection/dependency')
    .useClass(DbOjectMockIAmUsing)
.overrideProvider('@another/string/injection/dependency')
    .useValue('@another/string/injection/dependency')
.overrideProvider(DbConnection)
    .useValue({
        selectOne: () => null,
        selectAll: () => null
    })
.compile()
```

I also tried using Jest to override the classes

```
Jest.mock('@path/to/dbconnection', () => {
    selectOne: () => null,
    selectAll: () => null
}))
```

All didn't seem to have any effect.

I tried `spyOn()`

```
jest.spyOn(DbConnection, 'selectOne').mockImplementation(() => null);
jest.spyOn(DbConnection, 'selectAll').mockImplementation(() => null);
```

but I seem to get a strange error

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 4, '(object: typeof DbConnection, method: never): SpyInstance<never, never>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  Overload 2 of 4, '(object: typeof DbConnection, method: never): SpyInstance<never, never>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2769)
```

I understand that testing the controller is 'good enough' but I am still curious what I am doing wrong, as I am sure I will find a use case for this testing method in future.

**EDIT:**

It turns out I was encountering two problems. Firstly, for whatever reason, I struggled to have Jest mock a method of a class. As per @Estus Flask's suggestion, I can now at least mock/stub methods

```
import { DbConnection } from '@some/path';

jest.spyOn(DbConnection.prototype, 'selectOne').mockReturnValue(null);
```

Secondly, nearly all tutorials explaining to mock using the explicit import path

```
import { DbConnection } from '@some/path';

jest.mock('@some/path');
DbConnection.mockReturnValue(null);
```

left out the detail about typescripts type checking which [I discovered from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48759035/mock-dependency-in-jest-with-typescript?rq=1) causing issues.

```
let myMock = <jest.Mock<DbConnection>>DbConnection;
```

While the initial error described above was different, the type casting and examples from the linked answer solved a lot of confusion.

Still, given there is a bounty, perhaps someone can explain why the `providers` array is pretty much ignored when the `import` array contains the `AppModule`

Comment: The question doesn't contain enough information. What exactly did you with jest.mock and jest.spyOn and what was the problem (the exact error message)? Please, provide test code that you used for them. jest.mock was likely used incorrectly, otherwise it should work. And if `DbConnection` is a class, methods should be mocked on `DbConnection.prototype`. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for the example with overrideProvider, I'd expect it to work. How did you confirm that stubs are ignored?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else coming across this question, the problem (at least in my case) is using

```
imports: [AppModule]
```

From what I can tell, Nest resolves all dependencies itself when using `imports` and since the `AppModule` is the module that basically loads all the app dependencies, it seems that for whatever reason, all the classes I give in the `providers` array are ignored.

To solve this I just had to use my original method but call the HTTP server like so

```
const response = await request(server).get('myUrl');
```

So the final structure was

```
describe('Working stubbed controller test', () => {
    let app;
    let server;

    beforeAll(async () => {
        const moduleFixture = await Test.createTestingModule({
            controllers: [MyController],
            providers: [
                ObjectInjectionDependency,
                {
                    provide: '@string/injection/dependency',
                    useClass: DbOjectMockIAmUsing
                },
                {
                    provide: '@another/string/injection/dependency',
                    useClass: AnotherClassIAmUsing,
                },
                {
                    provide: DbConnection,
                    useValue: {
                        selectOne: () => null,
                        selectAll: () => null
                    }
                }
            ]
        })
        .compile();

        app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
        server = app.getHttpServer()
        await app.init();
    });

    it('/GET url', async () => {
        const response = await request(server).get('myUrl');
        
        expect(response.body.data).toBe('stuff');
    });
});
```

Teardown methods not included