# Mocking a class dependency in jest with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

> *I have read [Mock dependency in Jest with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48759035/mock-dependency-in-jest-with-typescript), [Typescript and Jest: Avoiding type errors on mocked functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51495473/typescript-and-jest-avoiding-type-errors-on-mocked-functions), and many other articles on Stack Overflow, but while I can get this code working for one test, I can't get it working for two tests.*

I am using `ts-jest` and Postgres. I have working code to make a mock of the `Pool()` constructor, and the pool instance has a `query()` method that returns some mock data.

```
import { describe, expect, test } from "@jest/globals";
import { checkLimits } from "./db";
import { MINUTES } from "./constants";
const log = console.log;

// Make a mock for the pg Pool constructor
jest.mock("pg", () => {
  return {
    Pool: jest.fn(() => ({
      query: jest.fn(() => {
        return {
          rows: [
            {
              timestamps: [Date.now() - 10 * MINUTES],
            },
          ],
        };
      }),
    })),
  };
});

describe("checkLimits", () => {
  test("allows reasonable usage by address", async () => {
    await checkLimits("abcdef");
  });
});
```

**This code works**.

What I would like to do, and have attempted to do unsuccessfully, is to be able to use `mockedQuery.mockReturnValueOnce()` in my tests.

So I can do:

```
describe("checkLimits", () => {
  test("allows reasonable usage by address", async () => {
    mockedQuery.mockReturnValueOnce({
      rows: [
        {
          timestamps: [Date.now() - 10 * MINUTES],
        },
      ],
    });
    await checkLimits("abcdef");
  });

  test("also allows on more usage", async () => {
    mockedQuery.mockReturnValueOnce({
      rows: [
        {
          timestamps: [
            Date.now() - 10 * MINUTES,
            Date.now() - 3 * MINUTES,
            Date.now() - 2 * MINUTES,
          ],
        },
      ],
    });
    await checkLimits("abcdef");
  });
});
```

However, between JS hoisting issues, ts-jest deprecations, and other complexity, I just can't seem to do it.

**How can I use `mockedQuery.mockReturnValueOnce()` in my mocked Postgres implementation?**

Comment: Can you give an example where `mockedQuery` is actually defined? Jest has [specific behaviour](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmock-with-the-module-factory-parameter) for values prefixed with `mock...` to get around `jest.mock` call hoisting. But really you shouldn't be mocking `pg` at all; it's a complex interface you don't own (just look at that multi-layered test double). It's much more straightforward to test at an _integration_ level and, if necessary, test the core logic against a test double of a simpler persistence abstraction (wrapper around `pg`) that _you own_.

Comment: So mockedQuery would be an implementation of the regular `pool.query()` method. Totally happy to only mock at a lower level if I can work out how. Thanks for the heads up re: "Jest will disable this check for variables that start with the word mock." I'll investigate that now. Did you vote to close, if so, can you please be friendly and add a comment about what's wrong or what to improve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting an answer to help others with the same issue. I wasn't able to get `mockReturnValueOnce()` working, but was able to create a variable for the mock data and set that after each test.

If someone else posts an answer using `mockReturnValueOnce()` I'll accept that instead.

```js
import { describe, expect, test } from "@jest/globals";
import { Row, checkLimits } from "./db";
import { Pool } from "pg";
import { MINUTES } from "./constants";
const log = console.log;

let mockRows: Array<Row> = [];

// Make a mock for the pg Pool constructor
jest.mock("pg", () => {
  return {
    Pool: jest.fn(() => ({
      query: jest.fn(() => {
        return {
          rows: mockRows,
        };
      }),
    })),
  };
});

describe("checkLimits", () => {
  test("is fine when there's no previous usage", async () => {
    mockRows = [];
    await checkLimits("some ok value");
  });

  test("allows reasonable usage", async () => {
    mockRows = [...snip...];
    await checkLimits("some ok value");
  });

  test("blocks unreasonable usage", async () => {
    mockRows = [...snip...];
    await expect(checkLimits("some bad value")).rejects.toThrow(
      "some error"
    );
  });
});
```